# TCL (VMD scripts) functions in python

Tags: python, tcl, simulation, vmd

I have access to a bunch of TCL scripts but some of them are not working fast and I want to convert some of them to python. Does anybody have any experience?  ex. one of the functions that I faced problem with it is pbwithin in TCL and I do not understand it well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please don't assume that Python will be faster than Tcl.

Comment: If you have the proc code for `pbwithin` you can ask for suggestions of how to speed it up.

Comment: `pbwithin` appears to be something built-in to VMD, which few Tcl people are familiar with.  If `pbwithin` is important to your question you may get better-informed responses if you ask at https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vmd .